# Django: Call custom function within generic views

Tags: python, django, function, django-generic-views

I'm new to Django and am using Django's [generic editing views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/) to add/edit/delete entities. Eg, the views for adding and editing look like this:

```py
class QuoteCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'quotes/quote_form.html'
    model = Quote
    fields = ['quote_text']


class QuoteUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Quote
    fields = ['quote_text']
```

This works fine and I'm happy with how everything is rendered. I'd just like to call an extra, custom function whenever a new object is created or edited (to send myself notifications). How can I do that? I couldn't find anything useful in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a view within another, which in your example could look like:

**views.py**

```
class QuoteCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'quotes/quote_form.html'
    model = Quote
    fields = ['quote_text']
    object_change = notify_function(foo)


class QuoteUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Quote
    fields = ['quote_text']
    return = fields
    object_change = notify_function(foo)


def notify_function(foo):
    # whatever logic is desired to be notified
    return [..]
```

Comment: So this would call my update view from the create view? What I want is to call a custom function *in addition*  to the current logic? I still want object creation and update to work as they currently do, using Django's generic views. I just want to have an additional function call that logs that (and which) object was created/updated. I do not want to have to implement creating/updating/rendering myself.

Comment: @CGFoX ah got your point now. Then I suggest to set up a new function and call that within both CreateView and UpdateView basically

Comment: Thanks, this is going in the right direction. But adding the function as `object_change` attribute leads to calling the function once when I start the server, but not whenever a quote/object is created/updated (which is what I want). Am I doing sth wrong here or is that another attribute that I need to use? Is there any documentation on `object_change` and the like?

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite generic view post method putting your function in it.

```
class QuoteUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Quote
    fields = ['quote_text']
    
    def my_custom_function(self):  
        # your code
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.my_custom_function()
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```